# How do I debug ASP.NET websites in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

How do I debug ASP.NET websites in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)? Their website says that it has support for C# and Razor code, so I'm just assuming you can debug ASP.NET pages, since it also has a Debug button on the left toolbar.

Their instructions on their website are lacking (in my opinion) and I don't see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visual Studio Code and ASP.NET 5 are in preview and at this time debugging ASP.NET 5 is not supported in Visual Studio Code (on any platform).

[Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/ASPnet5)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the navigation menu on the right side of the page. Thanks @Widi.